# .htaccess rewrite index GET request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, url-rewriting

So, I want to rewrite my url from this:
http://example.com/l1
to
http://example.com/?loc=l1

Currently I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ./?loc=$1 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

But each time I type http://example.com/l1 it gives me a 404 error! Please help!

Comment: Why do you specify a relative path in there (`./`)? Relative to _what_? Make it absolute, I'd say...

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Em... strange question... `./` is a relative path. That does not make sense where you place it, if I am not totally mistaken. Use an absolute path instead, so one starting with `/`, not with `./`. So: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /?loc=$1 [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?loc=$1 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

I do not rewrite the links to existing files with `!-f`.
And URI in RewriteRule does not begin with a `/`